# How I can put roman numbers in a subsubsection title?

Tags: roman-numerals, subsection

I have this code:

> `\subsubsection{subsubsection}`
>
> in this subsubsection I have one text
>
> `\subsubsection{subsubsection||}`
>
> Plus text in this subsubsection

But when i pu the `||` (2 in roman numbers) my compiler (overleaf - XeLaTex) does not do that I want.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What would you like the output to look like?

Comment: Are you sure that `||` is what you want? Why not `II`? Please also be more specific as to what "my compiler does not do what I want" entails.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community want to know if there is any package that "helps" me writing roman numbers

Comment: @Mico is a good option, but i prefer to do it with a package, if there exists any one

Comment: this doesn't appear to have anything to do with subsections, you do want `II` not `||`  if you want tex to work out the characters, use `\UseName{@Roman}{2}`

Comment: @Euricky999 please upvote if the answer met your expectations

Comment: If I could... I don't have enough reputation. Only +2 more and I will be the first to upvote your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the comment of @David Carlisle

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Section}
    
    Some text in the section.
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
    Some text in the subsection.
    
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
    
    In this subsubsection, I have some text.
    
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection\ \UseName{@Roman}{2}}
    
    Additional text in this subsubsection.
    
\end{document}
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{Subsubsection \Roman{subsubsection}}

\subsubsection{Title of the subsubsection}

Text of the subsubsection

\subsubsection{Title of the second subsubsection}

Text of the subsubsection
```

Output:

[image]